# How do I unpack .zip via FTP on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, ssh, ftp, zip

I uploaded this .zip file using FTPRush to some FTP, now I need it to unpack, but can't figure out how. On FTPRush there's this command prompt when you click CTRL+R it's titled Send Raw Command to Site. So was wondering is there a command to send to unpack the zip?

I always used to upload just unpacked files, but this zip has like thousands of files packed, that would be crazy to upload each and every.

Or is there no chance and I must get SSH access? I have used it once via PuTTY, but don't have access now to that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such FTP command. There could be vendor-specific extensions, but that’s a long shot.

With shell access, this would be trivial, of course.

Still, there is yet another possibility: Unpacking via PHP/Perl/whatever. Ready-made solutions for this are available.